# GtkListBox, how to prevent auto-selecting a row on window show

Tags: pygtk, gtk3

I have a list box with several rows attached to a window.

```
list_box = Gtk.ListBox()
list_box.insert(Gtk.Label('foo'), -1)
list_box.insert(Gtk.Label('bar'), -1)
list_box.insert(Gtk.Label('qux'), -1) # ListBoxRow is added automatically

window = Gtk.Window()
window.add(list_box)
window.show_all()
```

When I call `show_all()`, the first row of the list is being selected automatically what I don't want to happen. How to prevent auto-selecting it? 
I tried changing the order of the functions call

```
window.show_all()
window.add(list_box)
```

which broke the layout and the size of the window doesn't fit to the list.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this issue as well, I used the following code to do it:

```
listbox = Gtk.ListBox(margin=0)
listbox.set_selection_mode(Gtk.SelectionMode.NONE)
```

I can still click on each row and do a callback with the following, as well:

```
listbox.connect("row-activated", self.callback)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ListBox` has a property `selection-mode`, which you can set to `Gtk.SELECTION_NONE`. In this case none of the rows will be selected (and cannot be selected later). I don't know if that is what you want.

You can also call the method `unselect_all`, which will unselect all rows. For this to work, the ListBox must be in SELECT_MULTIPLE or SELECT_SINGLE mode.

This example seems to work completely as expected (i.e. no selection at the start, and if a line is selected, the button can unselect it). If in your installation it doesn't work, I would try to update your packages:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.connect("delete-event", self.on_delete)

        self.listbox = Gtk.ListBox()
        self.listbox.insert(Gtk.Label('foo'), -1)
        self.listbox.insert(Gtk.Label('bar'), -1)
        self.listbox.insert(Gtk.Label('qux'), -1) # ListBoxRow is added automatically

        button = Gtk.Button("Clear selection")
        button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_clicked)

        vbox = Gtk.VBox()
        vbox.pack_start(button, False, True, 0)
        vbox.pack_start(self.listbox, False, True, 0)

        self.add(vbox)
        self.show_all()

        Gtk.main()

    def on_button_clicked(self, btn):
        self.listbox.unselect_all()

    def on_delete(self, win, event):
        Gtk.main_quit()


def main():
    w = MainWindow()

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

A note about gtk3 themes: Some themes do not show selected rows at all. Particularly dark themes such as eg. FlatStudioDark, but also some light themes.

Comment: I need the rows to be selectable, but I don't want any of them to be selected by default just after the program is started.

Comment: I tried the ListBox here (I never used it before), but I have the impression that there is *always* a row selected. You could try setting the mode to Gtk.SELECTION_NONE, and then back to SELECT_SINGLE, to see if that works. Do you need single or multiple selection?

Comment: Your example program doesn't work as I need because on window display the button is focused, when I delete button or move it to the bottom, the focus is given to ListBox and the first row is selected.
However, playing with selection modes solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add a dummy label to the top of your list_box and hide it:

```
dummyLabel = Gtk.Label('nothing') # workaround for focus of title entry
list_box.insert(dummyLabel, -1)
list_box.insert(Gtk.Label('foo'), -1)
list_box.insert(Gtk.Label('bar'), -1)
list_box.insert(Gtk.Label('qux'), -1)  # ListBoxRow is added automatically
window = Gtk.Window()
window.add(list_box)
window.show_all()
dummyLabel.hide()
Gtk.main()
```

The result:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdNHt.png)